# How to set a hash key using a variable in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby

I have a variable that is a string. I want to create a hash using the variable as a key. In Ruby 1.8, I used the hashrocket syntax, like this:

```
my_key = 'arbitrary'
my_hash = {my_key => 'my_value'}
```

In Ruby 1.9, there is a new syntax and I can do this:

```
my_hash = {arbitrary: 'my_value'}
```

But how do I do convert the variable to a key? I tried:

```
my_key = 'arbitrary'
my_hash = {:my_key 'my_value'} 
my_hash = {my_key.to_sym: 'my_value'}
my_hash = {:my_key.to_sym 'my_value'} 
my_hash = {my_key.to_sym 'my_value'}
```

Do I have to continue to use the Ruby 1.8 syntax?

Comment: You do not need to apply any modifications to your existing code. Hashrockets still work.

Comment: AFAIK you could also go with `my_hash[my_key] = 'my_value'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me introduce you two ways to do what you exactly want. If you don't want to continue using 1.8 syntax and hashrockets anymore, **ruby-doc.org** recommends doing it in this way in Ruby 1.9.3:

```
my_hash = Hash.new

my_key = "key000"
my_hash[my_key] = "my_value"
```

Livedemo: http://ideone.com/yqIx2M

Second one (more similar to what you are trying to achieve) is:

```
my_key = "key0"
my_hash = Hash[my_key, "value00"]

puts my_hash
```

Livedemo: http://ideone.com/HHLyAi

Answer (score 4):

`{arbitrary: 'my_value'}` is syntactic sugar for `{:arbitrary => 'my_value'}`, and `:arbitrary` is syntactic sugar for `'arbitrary'.to_sym`(yes, this is a lie, since `:arbitrary` interns when the interpreter reads the code and `'arbitrary'.to_sym` interns when it executes the code, but for the sake of the explanation let's pretend they're equivalent)

So, `{arbitrary: 'my_value'}` can be written as `{'arbitrary'.to_sym => 'my_value'}`, and since you have the key in a variable, you can use:

```
my_key = 'arbitrary'
my_hash = {my_key.to_sym => 'my_value'}
```

Keep in mind though that when you use `to_sym` you are risking creating lots of symbols, which will stay in memory forever(ish), so you might want to consider using string-keys with your old syntax. For more info about the difference between strings and symbols read this: http://www.randomhacks.net/2007/01/20/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-ruby-symbol/

Comment: Ruby does collect Symbols from 2.2 on.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby 1.9 syntax applies only to `Symbol` literals. With anything else, that is keys not being `Symbol`, or not being literals (like in your example), you still need to use hashrocket.